# How to access last node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to make a simple figure using TikZ.

[image: Simple figure]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{memory/.style={draw,minimum width = 100pt, minimum height = 25pt, node distance = 0}}

  % Draw memory cells with addresses.
  \newcounter{add}  % memory address
  \setcounter{add}{202}
  \node [memory, label=left:0x\theadd] (a)  {a};
  \stepcounter{add}  % name of above node
  \newcounter{aboveNode}
  \setcounter{aboveNode}{1}
  \foreach \n in {b,c,d,e,f} {
    \node [memory, label=left:0x\theadd, below = of {\alph{aboveNode}}] (\n)  {\n};
    \stepcounter{add}
    \stepcounter{aboveNode}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems to me that I should be able to do this without having to use the `aboveNode` counter. I found out about `\tikzlastnode` but using it as follows does not work.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{memory/.style={draw,minimum width = 100pt, minimum height = 25pt, node distance = 0}}

  % Draw memory cells with addresses.
  \newcounter{add}
  \setcounter{add}{202}
  \node [memory, label=left:0x\theadd] (a)  {a};
  \stepcounter{add}
  \foreach \n in {b,c,d,e,f} {
    \node [memory, label=left:0x\theadd, below = of \tikzlastnode] (\n)  {\n};
    \stepcounter{add}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX gives the error

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> of \tikzlastnode 

l.20       }
```

Is there some way to access the last node drawn? Or a simpler way to draw my diagram? At the moment I use more lines than if I had drawn each node manually.

### UPDATE

As pointed out in [the answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186413/44301), `remember` can be used to get rid of the `aboveNode` counter. Can the `add` counter be similarly eliminated?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks! I am a frequent visitor and find the site extremely useful. This is the first time I have not found a solution to my problem here and had to post my own question.

Comment: You came to the right place, and your first question is formulated in an examplary fashion :)

Comment: This diagram could be done with a `tabular`, do you need a `TiKZ` solution for any special reason?

Comment: I am getting into `TikZ` so I thought to start off with something simple. Also, what I showed above is part of the eventual diagram which contains another table and arrows between the cells of the tables. `TikZ` provides good arrows though I am sure there are other options. It seems to me that I can get most diagramming tasks done with just `TikZ`,  whereas I would otherwise need to learn several different packages for different tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated** You can use the `remember` key to access the name of the last node, and use `count` key to replace the `add` counter. For people still using PGF 2.10, chaning the variable list from `{b,c,d,e,f}` to `{b,...,f}` will overcome a bug in that version.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{memory/.style={draw,minimum width = 100pt, minimum height = 25pt, node distance = 0}}

  % Draw memory cells with addresses.
  \node [memory, label=left:0x{202}] (a)  {a};
  \foreach \n[remember=\n as \lastn (initially a), count=\ctr from 203] in {b,...,f} {
    \node [memory, label=left:0x\ctr, below = of \lastn] (\n)  {\n};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should use `\lastn` instead of `\j`; `\lastn` would be more descriptive.

Comment: Very strange. I cannot post a picture of the output in the comment but on my system your code draws node 'a' and then draws nodes 'b' onward all on top of each other just below 'a'.

Comment: @wsaleem Kevin's code produces the expected output here. Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: @Jubobs: Notation updated. Thanks for the suggestion `:)`

Comment: @wsaleem: I'm using TikZ 3.0. But I don't think 2.10 would make a difference... Perhaps try to delete the `.aux` file and compile again using the updated code?

Comment: Seems recent enough. `latex --version` yields `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).`

Comment: @wsaleem: Try putting `TikZ version: \pgfversion.` somewhere in your document and see if your PGF package is up to date. Mine is `3.0.0`.

Comment: TikZ version: 2.10

Comment: @wsaleem It is a known problem and fixed in the new version. Add `\def\lastn{a}` before the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: Hmm... no change after adding `\def\lastn{a}` before the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: @wsaleem Oops, sorry then change the variable list to `{b,...,f}`. One or the other should work :) It's a strange bug

Comment: Thanks. Changing to `{b,...,f}` makes it work even with the `\def\lastn{a}` removed. Maybe @KevinC can update his answer accordingly. Can I use `remember` to also get rid of the `add` counter? I will update the original post to include this query.

Comment: @wsaleem: answer updated `:)`